# Dynamic button groups in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wonder if there is a way to make button group dynamic,
example: http://www.bootply.com/lkJQ2WDubH
in result you can see first line and second line.

How would I create or make it dynamic so that when I click on button it adjust position and gets active state?

When button 1 is active:

[image]

When button 2 is active:

[image]

and so on...

So one button group or toolbar that acts like those 2 groups, right now it is duplicate code.

Idea is that active button stands out, but right now it is duplicate code and perhaps there is more dynamic solution, appreciate guidance or help.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">7</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First groups">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">7</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is happening in that link that you want to emulate?It seems like two pretty much unconnected buttons from the fiddle

Comment: Right now each groups has 7 buttons and those are hard coded. Instead of that you should be able to pass number of buttons to be shown?

Comment: right now it is duplicate buttons, i want one button group that acts like those 2 groups

Comment: It would require a substantial markup change for each event. Why not just more dramatic active-state button styling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">6</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary new">7</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, with a little bit of jquery, you can add a class to the clicked button and remove it from others to achieve any style you want on clicked button:

```
  $("button.new").click(function() {
      $("button.new").removeClass("buttonChange").removeClass("buttonRoundLeft").removeClass("buttonRoundRight");
     $(this).addClass("buttonChange");
     $(this).prev().addClass("buttonRoundLeft");
     $(this).next().addClass("buttonRoundRight");
 });
```

The required CSS classes look like this:

```
.buttonChange  {
    margin: 0 10px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
 }

 .buttonRoundLeft {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
 }
 .buttonRoundRight {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
 }
```

Check out a working example on [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/EPOgOP)

**UPDATE:**

Easier way to do it is to just have a class for the focus state of the button like this:

```
button.new:focus {
   margin: 0 10px !important;
   border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

This only works if you do not want to have rounded corner for adjacent buttons. It is easy to do it for the next button using the same syntax but not possible for the previous button.

Comment: Not bad, but not truly a separate group solution (no border radius handling).

Comment: you want the button to have rounded corner? Then check out updated answer

Comment: It's not my question, but I was referring to the adjacent buttons (which would have rounded corners at the outside of the group).

Comment: That's easy to achieve by jQuery. Check out my updated answer to address your concern @isherwood

Comment: your html markup is the issue. you should modify it according to my answer

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeQVVY I made fork of your code and added slightly different code, but it is not working...

Comment: that's because you have new html markup. Your button is <label class="btn ... So you need to change your selector in the jQuery code. check it here  http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/obQYBp

Comment: Oh I see, but it doesn't fix active state in this case...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102926/discussion-between-karma-and-zero-point).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("li.btn").click(function() {
   $("li.btn").removeClass("buttonSelect");
   $(this).addClass("buttonSelect");
});
```

```css
.buttonSelect  {
  margin: 0 10px !important;
}

li.btn:focus {
   margin: 0 10px !important;
   border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <ul class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">6</li>
    <li type="button" class="btn btn-primary">7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Check this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeVKor)